# How to re-draw D3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to update my bar chart when I select a value by radio button. This value is passed as a parameter of my query in order to obtain corresponding JSON data.

The code works fine, excluding one aspect. When I select a value by clicking any radio button, the bar chart is drawn on top of existing bar chart. I want the chart to be re-drawn each time I select a new option.

```
// set the dimensions of the canvas
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// set the ranges
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// define the axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var compSvg = d3.select(".company");

var companies = [];
d3.json("http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=popularity:[10%20TO%20*]&wt=json&fl=cat&facet=true&facet.field=cat", function(error, resp) {

    var results = resp.facet_counts.facet_fields.cat;
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var value = results[i*2];
        companies.push(value);
    }
});


//functions for toggling between data
function change(value){
    update(value);
}

function update(comp){
    var query = 'cat:"' + comp + '"';

    var url = "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/select?q=" + encodeURIComponent(query) + "&rows=10&fl=manu,price&wt=json"


    // load the data
    d3.json(url, function(error, resp) {

          if (error) return console.error(error);

          resp.response.docs.forEach(function(d) {
                d.manu = d.manu;
                d.price = +d.price;
          });

          // scale the range of the data
          x.domain(resp.response.docs.map(function(d) { return d.manu; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(resp.response.docs, function(d) { return d.price; })]);

          // add axis
          compSvg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "x axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll("text")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .attr("dx", "-.8em")
              .attr("dy", "-.55em")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

          compSvg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", 5)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Price");


          // Add bar chart
          compSvg.selectAll("bar")
              .data(resp.response.docs)
            .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("class", "bar")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.manu); })
              .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.price); })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.price); });

    });

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `d3.selectAll("bar").remove();` and placing it as the first item in the call?

Comment: `compSvg.selectAll("bar")` will always give you an empty selection, thus the enter selection, after settting the data, will always append new rectangles. Try: `compSvg.selectAll(".bar") - you are appending `rect` elements with the class `bar`, not `bar` elements.

Comment: @AndrewReid That's an improvement, but it will make little difference: OP only has an "enter" selection, no update or exit selections. That's his/her problem here.

Comment: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jbanegas/pen/dRBoRE?editors=1011)  showing what I mean. It uses a line chart though.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, yep, I realize that, I could have been clearer on that being only one issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the charts for the first time, everything works as expected: you have a null selection, and the enter selection creates an element for every item in the data array. You also append axes.

When you load the charts the second time with the `change` function, you repeat what you did to create the charts in the first place: you have a null selection, as `selectAll("bar")` will be empty, and the enter selection creates a new element for every item in the data array. You also append axes.

You need to use the update and exit selections to properly make this work:

After the initial data is appended you need to use an update selection to modify the bars, an enter to bring in new bars (if one dataset uses more bars than another), and an exit selection to exit unneeded bars (if one dataset uses less bars than another). There is a lot of information online on the enter, update, exit process; keep in mind there are differences between v4 and v3.

This looks like:

```js
var data = [
  [1,2,3,4,5],
  [6,4,3],
  [5,10,1,7,1,3]
];

var i = 0;

var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);
  
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);


update(data[0]);
timer();

function update(dataset) {

  // update scales
  y.domain([0,d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d; })] );
  x.domain(dataset.map(function(d,i) { return i; }) );
  
  // Bind Data
  var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(dataset);
    
  // Update existing bars:
  bars.transition()
    .attr("x",function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .attr("y",function(d) { return y(d); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand() )
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d); })
    .duration(1000);
    
    
   // New Bars 
   bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","bars")
    .attr("x",function(d,i) { return x(i); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand() )
    .attr("y",height)
    .attr("height",0)
    .transition() 
    .attr("y",function(d) { return y(d); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d); })
    .duration(1000);;
    
   // Un-needed Bars:
   bars.exit()
    .transition()
    .attr("height", 0)
    .duration(1000)
    .remove();
   
}

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() { update(data[i++%3]); timer() } , 1500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

A little modification may meet your need:

```
function change(value){
    // erase all contents before update
    compSvg.html("");
    update(value);
}
```